# Can't see shared files when connecting to server using hostname, but can using IP

Tags: dns

When I access my server using the DNS name, for example:

```
\\myserver.local\
```

I can see the shares but cannot see any files within the shares. I've  tried disabling the firewall and checked to make sure things like SSDP are enabled. However I am still unable to see any files via the DNS name.

If I access the server via its IP, I can see all files without any issues. What could be causing this?

Comment: What is the  OS on the server and the client

Comment: windows server 2008 r2

Answer (score 0):

Try an ipconfig /flushdns .
Can happen when one PC is not part of the domain.
You can then edit your HOSTS file using a pointer.... eg. 10.1.10.1    myserver.local